# What is this stack people keep talking of?

Tags: architecture, startup

For some time now, I've been looking at the tech startup scene, and one word that bothers me is the word "STACK", a lot of startups talk about how they supply a 'stack' for developer.

Can anyone please explain what they are talking about?

Is stack the new word for middleware? Or some sort of Virtual Machine?

Comment: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/Web_stack.html

Comment: I believe it is a word for "I want to sound like I know what i am talking about but don't have a good grasp on what I'm really trying to say so i use an intentionally vague word'

Comment: The stack is a part of memory where local variables and function return addresses are stored. **C guy talking**

Comment: @gbtimmon, Thats what I suspect, especially when I look at the services they are selling..

Comment: @MartinKristiansen So is that "stack corruption"? :P

Comment: @H2CO3, Being a C/C++ guy myself that was what I was thinking -- but it does really not make sense, when they are selling web-app frameworks.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen Oh and let me see how they would create such a framework in PHP if there wasn't a PHP interpreter... written in... ***C!***

Answer (score 2):

A stack is a set of services that work together.  For example LAMP is a stack of linux machines using Apache, MySql, and Php (or python or perl).  They tend to be used one on top of the other, so they call it a stack.  Although really they're more like silos-  a few thing piled high next to each other (linux/apache/php and linux/mysql).